# find -daystart argument explanation

Tags: shell, find

So I understand that a line such as:

```
find /var/log/ -mtime +60 -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Will list all files in /var/log which were modified 60 days or more ago.

After reading through the find man page though I noticed:

```
 Measure  times  (for  -amin,  -atime,  -cmin, -ctime, -mmin, and 
 -mtime) from the beginning of today rather than  from  24  hours
 ago.   This  option only affects tests which appear later on the
 command line.
```

Can someone explain the rest?  (-amin, -atime, -cmin, -ctime, -mmin) The man page itself does not seem to really declare what each of these do?

Some example questions which might help me understand:

- Find files modified an hour or more ago?
- Find files modified between 60 minutes and 10 minutes ago?
- Find files modified 2 weeks ago?
- Find files created in the last 5 minutes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - Find files modified an hour or more ago?

```
-mmin +60
```

> - Find files modified between 60 minutes and 10 minutes ago?

```
-mmin -60 -mmin +10
```

> - Find files modified 2 weeks ago?

```
-mtime +7 -mtime -8
```

> - Find files created in the last 5 minutes?

Can't be done. POSIX has no specification for creation time.

These options are explained in the **TESTS** subsection of the **EXPRESSIONS** section of the `find(1)` man page.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.  I suppose I needed to just read a bit more into it... my apologies.  -mtime is days, and the +/-<#> is the quantity for that given first part in this case days, or -mmin then some given minutes.